# SDKDKVer.h couldn't be opened (xp support)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting the attached error after having re-installed my computer and having simply re-installed VS2017.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?
I don't remember anymore what I did to include this header in the previous VS version.

My best guess would be that I downloaded a platform SDK, but I have no idea which one I should download using VS2017.

Thank you very much for an advice.

[image]

Edit: I already have this SDK installed: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

It doesn't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I selected Project->Properties->Windows SDK-Version->Default or Inherit from Standard.

And it worked.

It's now "7.0" as it had been before, but for some reason it works now.

Thanks to myself.

Also, I had to edit the Platform Toolset when I wanted to build the Release.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]